# TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined compId

Tags: angularjs, arrays

i have code like following

```
_this.data.opt[compId]
```

here the compid value is 1. when this value comes one means the javascript error cannot read the property 1 of undefined at compid.

Comment: opt is not defined - use a debugger or console statements to find out what _this and _this.data look like.

Comment: post us more code ...cant really figure out that `_this`

Comment: the opt object comes following  {"1":{}}

Comment: if can i check angular.isUndefinedorNull for this object ?